# Beats One turns off Airplay?

Tags: macos, itunes, airplay, itunes-radio

Anyone experiences the problem when swapping to the Radio (iTunes OSX), the Airplay function is switched off? Any fix?

> You can use Airplay when you set your "Output Device" to Airplay. But its a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be either a bug or a rights issue with Beats One. There is no fix at the moment.

A workaround is to choose your Airplay device as the system output. Option + click the sound icon in the taskbar and choose your Airplay device, or select it in Sound settings.

Source: http://www.mcelhearn.com/you-cant-play-beats-1-radio-over-airplay-from-itunes/

Comment: I would like to add that it is also possible to show Airplay in the task bar at all times, which would make switching faster. I will add where exactly, later. (On mobile now)